# Alignment of text using tabular environment

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a template for following image. Note: The width of signature block is equal to text width.

[image]

I have written following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Name}{Alpha Beta Gamma}
\newcommand{\Rank}{\LaTeX{} novice}
\newcommand{\Designation}{student}
\newcommand{\Organization}{MIT}
\newcommand{\OffExt}{3150}
\newcommand{\Encl}{\textbf{Encl:} as stated}

\newcommand{\SignatureBlock}{\vspace*{1.34in} \hfill \begin{tabular}{l l@{}}
    & \MakeUppercase{\Name} \\
    & \Rank \\
    & \Designation \\
    & \Organization \\
    \Encl & \OffExt \\
\end{tabular} }

\begin{document}
\SignatureBlock
\end{document}
```

I am unable to align the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Name}{Alpha Beta Gamma}
\newcommand{\Rank}{\LaTeX{} novice}
\newcommand{\Designation}{student}
\newcommand{\Organization}{MIT}
\newcommand{\OffExt}{3150}
\newcommand{\Encl}{\textbf{Encl:} as stated}

\newcommand{\SignatureBlock}{\par\vspace*{1.34in} 
\noindent\Encl \hfill \Longstack[l]{
    \MakeUppercase{\Name} \\
    \Rank \\
    \Designation \\
    \Organization \\
    \OffExt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\SignatureBlock
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "Encl" does not start at the start of line. It is indented. Is it possible to remove indention? I have tried \newcommand{\SignatureBlock}{\par \noindet \vspace*{1.34in} but there are some point space even then.

Comment: @AliBaig  Thanks...`\noindent\Encl`